# "No input file specified" Error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on this site   Backend works fine. IN the front end none of the other pages are displayed except index page.   the error come "No input file specified"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems there are many valid answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with your .htaccess file.

The fix:

Update to the latest WordPress. There is a permalink bug in some installations.

Make sure Apache is configured properly for ModRewrite.

From Support: On Options > Permalinks, is a section "Optional". It's not SO optional. After upgrading it mentioned for category's index.php/file (I've got the PATHINFO permalinks), I don't want "files" so I altered that to index.php/ Now that I've changed to index.php/_/ (or leave it blank which gives the standard "Category" subpath), its all working again. Here is the Mod Rewrite file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case it was the presence of a file named `.user.ini`

Just deleted it.

Comment: Which OS and server?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too, just don't know why is that, I'm using lnmp suite

Comment: @KhomNazid 
Server: LAMP with cPanel; 
Client: ALL

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.
On this server i have some about 70 WP instalation.
Whit one i got the same problem.

FIX - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> a few times ... and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP version! I update my php from 5.4.45 to 7.2.14 and my wordpress pulled up

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be bad permissions / ownership on the public_html files.  The error message is really not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of reasons that you could get the "no input file specified" error on WordPress.

In my case, it was because I was using php-fpm and I had specified the docroot incorrectly in the php-fpm pool configuration file. But that would probably be more likely to cause it for *all* pages, not just the front end pages.

In other cases, it might be a problem with either the Apache vhost configuration or the .htaccess as others have suggested.

File permissions also makes sense. Here's a link with more info on that in the nginx context: https://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/01/no-input-file-specified-with-php-and-nginx/

If it's related to permalinks, you may be able to go to the Permalinks section in the backend and rebuild those (as long as .htaccess is writable by your web server user).

Basically, I think the error is just saying "For some reason, I can't find the file that you are asking me to look for." But it isn't given the standard 404 ErrorDocument that Apache would give so it is confusing.

According to this answer on StackOverflow, this only happens when PHP is running under CGI or FastCGI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578219/263877. That's why it was unfamiliar to me, since I was used to mod_php.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it ended up being an issue with my php configuration. After rebuilding the php.ini, my site then pulled up.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue after a migration from a WordPress to a new wordpress (website recreated completely)

I’ve made a migration of the datas wth wp-migrate-pro.

iTheme Security was installed on the older WordPress ans was not deactivated. So the migration ended up with this error message.

I start all over again (and deactivated iTheme Security before the migration of the datas with wp-migrate-pro)