# No input file specified

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, anchor-cms

I'm running [Anchor CMS](http://anchorcms.com/) and I just upgraded to version 0.8. When I try and run the installer I get a 'No input file specified' error. I believe it's more than likely a .htaccess problem but I'm not sure what the correct settings should be.

My site can be found [here](http://coleroberts.me/anchor-cms-master/).

My .htaccess is set to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase {base}

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ {index} [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I'm also using a GoDaddy as the hosting provider if that helps.

Comment: There is not enough information given in this question. It is not possible to answer.

Comment: it can be .htaccess or your url settings (like seo, url rewriting) in admin or clear your server and website cache. for this go to your server account and try to endweb process.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, what other information should I provide? I appreciate your timely response.

Comment: _All_ information available: is that short string really _all_ you see? _Where_ do you see it? What is in the http servers log files? Access and error log? How does the `.htaccess` file you mention look like? What is the url you called? Or: what type of installer is that? ...

Comment: I ran into this issue for me with Laravel and my local env. Solution was to reprovision vagrant: `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The *No input file specified* is a message you are presented with because of the implementation of PHP on your server, which in this case indicates a CGI implementation (can be verified with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo)).

Now, to properly explain this, you need to have some basic understanding on how your system works with URL's. Based on your .htaccess file, it seems that your CMS expects the URL to passed along as a `PATH_INFO` variable. CGI and FastCGI implementations do not have `PATH_INFO` available, so when trying to pass the URI along, PHP fails with that message.

We need to find an alternative.

One option is to try and fix this. Looking into the documentation for [core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo) you can see that you can change the workings for your implementation. Although, GoDaddy probably won't allow you to change PHP settings on a shared enviroment.

**We need to find an alternative to modifying PHP settings**
Looking into `system/uri.php` on line 40, you will see that the CMS attempts two types of URI detection - the first being `PATH_INFO`, which we just learned won't work - the other being the `REQUEST_URI`.

This should basically, be enough - but the parsing of the URI passed, will cause you more trouble, as the URI, which you could pass to `REQUEST_URI` variable, forces [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to only return the URL path - which basically puts you back to zero.

Now, there's actually only one possibilty left - and that's changing the core of the CMS. The URI detection part is insufficient.

Add `QUERY_STRING` to the array on line 40 as *the first element* in `system/uri.php` and change your .htaccess to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This will pass the URI you request to `index.php` as `QUERY_STRING` and have the URI detection to find it.

This, on the other hand, makes it impossible to update the CMS without changing core files till this have been fixed. That sucks...

**Need a better option?**
Find a better CMS.

Comment: Thanks! I had `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` (without question mark) in my .htaccess with ExpressionEngine on virtual shared hosting. That broke unexpectedly today with the error message from OP. I guess the web hoster updated something. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` (with question mark) fixed it.

Comment: is there is any way to intercept this error and replace by custom message ? (nginx)  thanks

Comment: I had:
`RewriteEngine On` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f `
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d `
`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`


...and it worked when I've just changed the last line to:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm upgrading a VERY old SlimPHP site that currently runs on PHP 5.3 and hit this issue. I was prepared for a long grind of googling but your fix solved it for me.

Answer (score 26):

Citing http://support.statamic.com/kb/hosting-servers/running-on-godaddy :

> If you want to use GoDaddy as a host and you find yourself getting "No input file specified" errors in the control panel, you'll need to create a `php5.ini` file in your weboot with the following rule:
>
> `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`

best easy answer just one line change and you are all set.

recommended for godaddy hosting.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to bring in the relevant code and explain. If a link becomes obsolete then your answer will mean nothing to future visitors.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked like a charm! Add `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1` to your php5.ini file

Comment: What about an application running on a local server (Laragon), with `PHP7` , what is the equivalent of your solution in such a case?

Answer (score 15):

In my case, there were an error in the php.ini open_basedir variable.

Comment: On Windows, this definitely can be a problem for executing any php scripts outside the basedir when a php script requires another. For example, if you have made a separate web directory outside C:\inetpub\wwroot. See more on the PHP ini documentation , but Under Windows, separate the directories with a semicolon. On all other systems, separate the directories with a colon. Note that this also is a security measure to also protect against PHP scripts outside the directory structure.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. All I did to fix the issue was to modify my htacces file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm/

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

GoDaddy is currently (Feb '13) supporting modification of FastCGI for some accounts using PHP 5.2.x or earlier.  See GoDaddy article "[Disabling FastCGI in Your Hosting Account](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7555/disabling-fastcgi-in-your-hosting-account?pc_split_value=1)".
(In my case, this is apparently necessary to help get the current version of LimeSurvey (2.0) towards a running state.)

Answer (score 3):

Adding php5.ini doesn't work at all.
But see the '**Disable FastCGI**' section in this article on GoDaddy: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5121/changing-your-hosting-accounts-file-extensions

Add these lines to .htaccess files (webroot & website installation directory):

```
Options +ExecCGI
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
```

It saves me a day! Cheers!
Thanks [DragonLord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841457/dragonlord)!

Answer (score 3):

disabling PHP-FPM fixed my issue.

Comment: This worked for me, i had php-fpm enabled on my vhosts on wampp, disabling it fixed  the issue!

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me..add on top of .htaccess file. It would disable FastCGI on godaddy shared hosting account.

**Options +ExecCGI**

**addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php**

Answer (score 2):

---

### Update

---

All the previous reviews were tested by me, but there was no solution. But I did not give up.

SOLUTION

**Uncomment the following lines in my NGINX configuration**

```
   [/etc/nginx/site-avaible/{sitename}.conf]
```

**The same code should follow in the site-enable folder**

```
  #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $ document_root $ fastcgi_script_name;
```

**And comment this:**

```
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME / www / {namesite} / public_html $ fastcgi_script_name;
```

**I changed several times from the original:**

```
   #fastcgi_pass unix: /var/php-nginx/9882989289032.sock;
```

**Going back to this:**

```
   #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9007;
```

**And finally I found what worked ...**

```
   fastcgi_pass localhost: 8004;
```

**I also recommend these lines...**

```
   #fastcgi_index index.php;
   #include fastcgi_params;
```

**And even the FastCGI timeout (only to improve performance)**

```
  fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
```

***During the process, I checked the NGINX log for all modifications.
(This is very important because it shows the wrong parameter.)*
In my case it is like this, but it depends on the configuration:**

```
  error_log/var/log/nginx/{site}_error_log;
```

**Test the NGINX Configuration**

```
 nginx -t
```

***Attention this is one of the options ...
Well on the same server, what did not work on this site works on others ... So keep in mind that the settings depends on the platform.***

In this case it was for Joomla CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ulimit -n 2048`

And restart php/php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove white space in one of my helper files.  The error listed two pages involved, a CI session file and one of my custom helpers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by butting the rules inside a [LocationMatch Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch)

```
<LocationMatch "^/.">
    #your rewrite rules here
</LocationMatch>
```

`/.` matches *any* location

I have the rewrite rules inside one of the `.conf` files of Apache **NOT `.htaccess` file.**

I don't know why this worked with me, this is my current setup

- Apache version 2.4
- PHP 7.1
- OS Centos 7
- PHP-FPM

Answer (score 0):

In my case giving a correct path to the root element in Nginx config.

changing root D:/fridoon/test/public; to root D:\fridoon\test\public; solved the issue.

then restart Nginx and php.

I am using Nginx in windows with Thinkcmf.com Chinese content management Framework. and also delete .user.ini file in the public directory some time this caused the above subject error.