# Codeigniter - 1 project - several domain names and several IP

Tags: codeigniter, symlink

I have 1 dedicated server.
The server has several IPs.
Some IP are dedicated for one particular domain.

```
Ip1 = mysite.be
Ip2 = mysite.fr
Ip3 = mysite.com
```

There is only one project. Each domain goes on the same location

My website is on /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs

For all other domain, i create a symlink.

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.be/httpdocs -> /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.fr/httpdocs -> /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs
```

...

When I go on mysite.com, all works.
But when i go on mysite.be ... I have an output from codeIgniter :

```
No input file specified.
```

I search more information about this error and I see that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578219/905867

My .htaccess fil is already well configured... I guess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css|js|uploads|modules|public|timthumb\.php|\.htpasswd|google.*\.html|captcha)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The fact that the domain linked with symlink display the error "No input file specified." proves that the symlink is OK and the acl on server are OK too (chown and chmod).

I think it's a little thing, but i don't know what. Anyone has a idea please ?

Some others information :
- I manage my server with plesk 11.0.9 #53
- My domain are "php as FastCGI module". If I use "as Apache Module, there is a blank page instead of error "No input file specified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes me long time but... problem is solved.

No input file specified wasn't a CodeIgniter error but a CGI/FastCGI error...

So I check on my plesk an I saw the domain are "PHP as FastCGI module" instead of "PHP as Apache Module".

But... instead of an error, I have a blank page.

Then I thought about open_basedir restriction. It was configured on "Webspaceroot" instead of "Docroot"... and "abracadabra" it works.

Take care !