# htaccess specified in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have some problem in .htaccess in codeigniter

it will generate the error
No input file specified and my url are http://cg.alpcube.com/index.php/home/register
if i remove index.php then it will work perfectly

And my .htaccess file are as under

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

How can i remove index.php  from url

Comment: possible duplicate of [No input file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Answer (score 0):

On your codeigniter folder add `.htaccess` and add this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your project name is **Example**
now in the project folder there will be a file **.htaccess**

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on
# Don't perform redirects for files and directories that exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# For everything else, redirect to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</ifModule>
```

write this into the .htaccess file

now just run this command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart your web server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the **.htaccess** which must be located at root of your project :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```