# Getting "No input file specified." only when PATH_INFO is empty?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I've installed [GitList](http://gitlist.org/) in a subdomain (PHP FastCGI 5.4.29). The following `.htaccess` comes with the default installation:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/gitlist/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
<Files config.ini>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

When I try to access `http:/subdomain.company.com` i get the following error:

> No input file specified.

I guess the error comes when `PATH_INFO` is empty, but I don't know how to fix it. If I access `http:/subdomain.company.com/index.php` the application works just fine.

And this is the directory structure, if can help:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln   435 Jun 30 05:07 boot.php
drwxrwxrwx  3 iosystit psacln  4096 Jul 20 04:09 cache
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln   831 Jul 20 11:14 config.ini
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln   975 Jun 30 05:07 config.ini-example
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln   291 Jun 30 05:07 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln   690 Jun 30 05:07 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln  2505 Jun 30 05:07 INSTALL.md
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln  1477 Jun 30 05:07 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 iosystit psacln  5358 Jun 30 05:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 iosystit psacln  4096 Jun 30 05:07 src
drwxr-xr-x  4 iosystit psacln  4096 Jun 30 05:07 themes
drwxr-xr-x 16 iosystit psacln  4096 Jul 20 04:05 vendor
```

**EDIT**: I accepted the answer because the link [No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified) pointed me to the solution, but I'm not using nginx:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to change some settings.

For exmaple for nginx there is a tip to make a change:

```
server {
    location = / {
        try_files @site @site;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location @site {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

More info at [Github](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/335). Also similar problem (but for different libraray) is at [No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Comment: I'm not using ngix, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified helped me to solve the problem. Don't know why adding the `?` fixed that...