# PHP: No input file specified?

Tags: php, dns, webserver, nas

Allright, So I have a webserver running on [nas4free](http://www.nas4free.org/),

Whenever I use my IP adress, all the the php files work and i'm able to use and execute php. But when I use my domain name (which should be the same since it only forwards to my domain) it tells me "no input file selected" and I have really no clue how to solve this.

Navigating to a file with phpinfo using my ip: `http://84.24.226.2/cp/servcheck.php`

Navigating to a file with phpinfo using domain: [Click Me](http://cp.grixcore.com/servcheck.php)

What could the problem be?

Content of servcheck.php:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: post the code contents of servcheck.php if you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [No input file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Comment: servcheck content is updated in first post, And I don't see how its a duplicate since it works on IP on not on Domain,

Comment: try http://WWW.domainname

Comment: That.. works.. I don't get it but it works. Thank you! Are you able to give some information how to get this working for subdomains aswell? or with plain domain without www?