# PHP error 'No input file specified.'

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm putting my wordpress site and another different php script folder in same directory location i.e. directory structure is as:

```
/myfolder
/wp-admin
/wp-content
/wp-includes
and other wp php files ...
```

My working URL looks like below:

```
http://example.com/myfolder/index.php/operationflag/value1/value2/value3/
```

when I try to open this url in browser it says `No input file specified.` But it is running normally `http://example.com/myfolder/index.php/`. Also wordpress site at `http://example.com/`working normally. I also viewed `.htaccess` but there is nothing more than these commented lines

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Please advise me what is the cause of this error message `No input file specified.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified this might help for you

Comment: No, I tied this already and this didn't worked, throws same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try open wp-admin and go to setting > permalink then without change anything click save button. Wordpress will create new `.htaccess` for your site.