# Magento Admin Not Working - After Login Redirect to Blank Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

Actually I am working on Magento.
I transferred my client site into my godaddy hosting.

My Application front end is working fine but Admin Panel did not work.

When I go to Admin Panel and Logged in. It will redirect to blank page.
And written `NO Input File Specified.`

My Application URL is like that.

https://subdomain.domain.info/index.php/myadmin_admin/index/index/key/baffe90052f021b4a2288ee9cdf58eb4/

I tried but I don't know where is the issue.

Can Any One please help me.

Any help will be appreciating.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No input file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Comment: I face the same issue .. Please check if eaccelerator cache is enabled on server ?

Comment: how do I check eaccelerator cache is enabled on server ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check link below site to resolve "No Input File Specified Error Hosted By Godaddy Magento Website "

[No Input File Specified Error Hosted By Godaddy Magento Website](http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/no-input-file-specified-error-hosted-by-godaddy-magento-website/)