# How to fix "No input file specified." in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, twig

I have created a website and used Twig PHP for templating and Toro PHP for routing. Here's the url of my site, http://imbilly.esy.es. And when I visit the contact page (http://imbilly.esy.es/contact), it shows "No input file specified.". 
I have no idea on how to fix this.

This is what inside in my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Contact form code:
[image]

Comment: show to code to the contact form so that so that the source of the problem can be seen.

Comment: possible duplicate of ::

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified

Comment: See my HTML contact form @SteveFerg.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0I9wDKKEoZSVlZzQndHU0g1d1U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```