# Laravel returns "No input file specified." after changing virtualhosts

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost, laravel-5.8

I recently installed a fresh copy of Laravel onto this test domain -http://laravel.so-mad.com/ using composer.
Install worked fine, if i navigated to http://laravel.so-mad.com/laravel/public then it all worked as it should.

I then began the task of editing to DocumentRoot on my server. editing the httpd.conf file directly wasn't an option as this gets automatically rebuilt whenever there is an update or the server is rebooted.

However, there is a file included if the file exists at 
    `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/somad/laravel.so-mad.com/*.conf`

I editied this file adding in the line
`DocumentRoot /home/somad/public_html/nobackup/laravel/laravel/public`

This.. I thought would allow my new laravel project to work from the domain root without having to navigate to /laravel/public.

However, as you can see by navigating to http://laravel.so-mad.com/ i just get the message `No input file specified.`

Any advice or help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after editing the conf? With „service apache2 restart“

Comment: Yeah, have done a few times now

Comment: Also enabled with a2ensite ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Comment: @Lukas yes its all enabled. It works fine until i change the location of DocumentRoot from `/home/somad/public_html/nobackup/laravel/` to this `/home/somad/public_html/nobackup/laravel/laravel/public`

Comment: @dparoli Its not quite the same as that. What your showing is based around mis config in the htaccess files. Whereas this works 100% perfectly right up until i change to DocumentRoot in apache config. I can empty the htaccess file and its still the same results