# No input file specified. CPANEL/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, cpanel

My Laravel application has been on my Cpanel for over 3years.
Today it started throwing Error `No input file specified.` when you visit my website.

I move the same code to a subdomain text.lamxxx.com and it work FINE.
But on my main domain is still throwing `No input file specified.`
I have been troubleshooting for over 24hrs.I checked the Server Log, check laravel log etc. But The website is still down.

BELOW IS MY .htacces

````
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit```
````

Comment: I used index.html and the website open it .... but when i tried to open a .php script it shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your issue is due to the **PHP version upgrade**,

- Try to modify your .htacces as explained in this previous post [No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)
- If the issue still persists try to revert back to the previous PHP version.

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing Php version from Cpanel and then check. I possible Please change to php 5.6 and check.