# No input file specified. / Symfony PHP Scripts / .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I am running an old website (decisions.ch) with a php script from Symfony. The script was coded back in 2008 and since then, the page was never updated. It ran very good until a couple of months ago. I assume that the problems were caused with new php settings from the hoster. At the moment, the site runs on PHP 5.6 FCGI.

I think that I should be possible to fix the site with new .htaccess settings as the hoster just lets me update some of the php.ini settings.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
#RewriteLog /home/www/web115/log/rewrite.log
#RewriteLogLevel 1

# Used to acces the PHP 52 # !!! USED ONLY ON HOSTSTAR #
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
Action php /cgi-php52/php

# Access to the admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php [L]

# So we redirect only some query to the symfony public controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+\.html$                      [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(kommentare|decision|suchen|erweiterte_suche|entscheide|absolutja|absolutnein|verwechslungsgefahr|keine_verwechslungsgefahr|gleichartige_waren|nicht_gleichartige_waren|verwechselbare_firmen|nicht_verwechselbare_firmen)(.*)$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public.php/%1%2                            [PT,QSA,L]
```

Does anybody has a hint where the error could be? I checked this forum with respect to other no input file posts in order to find something. So far, however, I was not successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.