# No input file specified error in Wordpress after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have a website http://reddelacruz.com/ which migrated `localhost` to the server. I believe that I configure everything fine including the database. I have this `woocommerce` plugin but when I view my product I have a page that says

```
No input file specified.
```

I've search the net and find that the error might came from the `.htaccess` as seen in this ["No input file specified" Error in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275755/no-input-file-specified-error-in-wordpress)

I followed his solution but did not work. Did I missed something? You can check my website and see the product section then click an item you'll see the error.

Comment: Have you enabled mod-rewrite for .htaccess? You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/840419

Comment: @SanathBallal I'm using GoDaddy hosting. Where should I enable mod-rewrite? I can't see any option to configure apache.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Issue is on the permalinks settings.

Comment: can you please help me tell me how did you solved this issue?